# how to filter data by formula instead of "filter function" below is example

Tags: excel

A1 has 0 
A2 has -2
A3 has 9
A4 has 0
A5 has 0
A6 has -1

i want to filter the above values in B column by excluding zero cells of A column like

B1 -2
B2 9
B3 -1

where 0(zero) is removed. Please help.

currently to do this i select A column then clicking on "filter" then selecting other than zero values and then pasting in B column. is it possible to do the same by formula? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A formula is not necessary if you copy ColumnA into ColumnB, replace `0` in ColumnB with nothing then select ColumnB, Go to Special, Blanks, OK, right click on one of the selection, Delete... and Shift cells up, OK.

Comment: wana avoid copying and want to do automatically. is it possible?